# Mulesoft Anypoint studio mule palette text missing

Tags: mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio, mulesoft, mule-esb

On Mulesoft Anypoint studio v7.7.0 on Windows 10 the Mule Palette shows no text next to any items when searching (See screenshot below)

The SHA256 was correct on download and I have also tried resetting the perspective.

Any ideas on how I can get the text of items in the Mule palette to display?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yn5xu.png)

Comment: Managed to fix this by setting override high DPI scaling behaviour. Scaling performed by system.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to fix this by setting override high DPI scaling behaviour. Scaling performed by system.